# Sending a newline in a response using Express and node.js

Tags: node.js, express, response, newline, line-breaks

I'm trying to send a string with a newline using Express.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

persons = [//...];

app.get('/info', (req,res) => {
    res.send(`Phonebook has info for ${persons.length} people.
    ${Date()}`);
});
```

I've read online that as of ES6, backticks can be used to construct multi-lines but it does not seem to be working.

My desired output is:

```
Phonebook has info for 4 people.

Thu Oct 10 2019 18:54:01 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
app.get('/info', (req,res) => {
    res.send(`Phonebook has info for ${persons.length} people.\n${Date()}`);
});
```

I've read online that you can also just use '\n' but that also does not work.

What am I doing wrong? I've been following the advice I've found online but I cannot get a new line to appear.

Comment: replace {Date()} with ${Date()}

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put ${Date}. That was a typo leaving the $ out. That didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: How is this payload being used? Or where? If it's HTML, then of course, `\n` wouldn't work, you'd need to convert them to `<br/>` tags. Unless this is pre-formatted text wrapped in `<pre></pre>` tags

Comment: Adding <br/> worked. My code is now `res.send(`Phonebook has info for ${persons.length} people` + `<br/>` +` ${Date()}`);`. I'm new to node.js and express so I did not realize res.send() should be sending HTML to my browser, which makes sense now that you've pointed it out. Thank you. What cases are there where res.send() would not be sending HTML?

Comment: When you are calling an endpoint from say a command line app for example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution was to use a `<br/>` tag instead of \n since the purpose of my res.send() was to send HTML to my local browser. Thanks to @Jason.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could separate the two sentences using HTML elements, e.g.

```js
app.get('/info', (req,res) => {
    res.send(`<p>Phonebook has info for ${persons.length} people.</p><p>${new Date()}</p>`);
});
```

Which should give you an output like:

> Phonebook has info for 4 people.
> Sat Jan 09 2021 18:34:35 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)